# Replace text from Excel To Word not consistent

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

It works for a few words then just puts the new word next to the previous one. For example, I'm trying to replace ex1 to eg1 then ex2 to eg2 then ex3 to eg3, but instead of replacing ex3 to eg3, it leaves ex3 alone and puts eg3 next to eg2.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceText()
Dim Path As String
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Dim keyword As String
Dim info As String
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True
wApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("file name")
For i = 3 To 73
keyword = Worksheets("Word").Cells(i, 2)
info = Worksheets("Word").Cells(i, 3)
With wDoc
    Worksheets("Word").Cells(4, 4).Value = keyword
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute FindText:=keyword, MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True, ReplaceWith:=info
    .Application.Selection = info
    .Application.Selection.EndOf
End With
Next i
    wDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=("file name"), _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scope of replacement is wrong. You have to look - each time - in the whole document.

This sub does the job

```vb
Sub replaceInWordDoc(doc As Word.document, lookFor As String, replaceWith As String)

'if nothing to look for we don't need to run replace
If LenB(lookFor) = 0 Then Exit Sub

With doc.Content.Find
    
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    .Text = lookFor
    .Replacement.Text = replaceWith

     .MatchCase = True
     .MatchWholeWord = True

    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

You can use it like this in your code

```vb
For i = 3 To 73
    keyword = Worksheets("Word").Cells(i, 2)
    info = Worksheets("Word").Cells(i, 3)
    replaceInWordDoc wDoc, keyword, infos
Next i
```